# VS2017 does not include Microsoft.Bcl.Build, yet VS2015 does

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sdk-.net

We are finding that Visual Studio 2017 does NOT include Microsoft.Bcl.Build in its package for an Azure Cloud Service (.NET Framework 4.5) project.  The same project built and packaged under Visual Studio 2015 does include Microsoft.Bcl.Build.

We determined if included or not when putting the package into production in Azure and the web roles reporting the missing dependency.  This can also be seen by comparing the bin folders as well.

Why doesn't VS 2017 include it as it should?

Here is a pic of the nuget dependencies for the project(s).
[image: nuget dependencies]

Comment: Because it doesn't have to. The `Bcl.Async`, Bcl.Build packages were only a stop-gap package for .NET 4.0 applications to allow them to use the `async/await` keywords. They are not needed in VS 2015 either if you target 4.5+. Your project shouldn't have a dependency on them in the first place

Comment: Perhaps you should *upgrade* your [Microsoft.Azure.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Common/) package? The latest version is 2.1.4 and doesn't have those dependencies

Comment: BTW Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql is also obsolete. It's 3 years old. The current package is [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'll go back and verify but I recall trying to upgrade the nuget packages required moving to a newer .NET version.  We are currently on .NET 4.5.

Comment: The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2 but the *new* packages *don't* require it, they'll add their own dependencies.

Comment: Anyway, check the package links and their dependencies. The latest `Microsoft.Azure.Common` package requires .NET 4.5 at minimum.

Answer (score 1):

The package [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql/) is obsolete and had no releases since 2015. It's been replaced by [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql) which has none of these dependencies. You should upgrade to that package.

Note that the Bcl packages are dependencies of an *old* version of [Microsoft.Azure.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Common/). That package doesn't require them in the current version either. If you can't upgrade to the latest Azure SQL Management package perhaps you should upgrade the Microsoft.Azure.Common package.

Neither VS 2015 nor VS 2017 will ever add Microsoft.Bcl or Microsoft.Bcl.Async. Those packages were created as a stop-gap measure back in 2012 to allow applications using C# 4 to use the `async/await` keywords. They added both the runtime and compiler extensions to understand the `async/await` keywords and generate the asynchronous state machine. Visual Studio 2012 itself was able to target C# 5 so it *didn't* need that package.

Those packages are only used by old libraries that haven't been upgraded to C# 5.

Comment: The new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql is marked "preview".  Is it production ready yet?  Would be nice if they had it noted on their https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/roadmap/?query=microsoft.azure.management.sql